# ルータとその接続機器のDNS設定について

Tags: network

ルータにDNSの設定があり、そのルータに何らかの方法で接続している機器にルータに設定しているDNSとは別のDNSを指定した場合、どちらのDNS設定が優先されるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

その機器にルータ以外のDNSを設定しているのであれば、その機器はルータがDNSの機能を持つことを知らないので特に問題は起きません。
ルータも、その機器からDNSの問い合わせが来なくても何の問題もありません。